# IOS: remove a subview when I type it out

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, subview

I have this code to show a subview and to remove it:

```
 if(view1 == nil){

    view1 = [[Calendar alloc] initWithNibName:@"Calendar" bundle:nil];
    [view1 setDelegate:self];

    [self.view addSubview:view1.view];
    view1.view.frame = CGRectMake(250, 0, 550, 400);

}
```

remove it:

```
[view1.view removeFromSuperview];
view1 = nil;
[view1 release];
```

it work fine when I push a button inside this subview "view1" but is possible remove this view also if I type out of this view?

Comment: What do you mean by type out? And set view1 = nil after view1 is release. First setting it to nil and then release has no good effect.

Comment: You've got some memory management issues in your code.  You should release view one after assigning it as a subview, and then don't worry about releasing in the later code.  Right now you are calling 'view1 = nil;' before calling release so you are just sending the release to nothing.

Comment: Please describe what you want to do in better English. Also try and be more clear when writing your code. view1 is not a view; it's a controller, so why call it view1?

Answer (score 2):

making it nil first before a release is pointless; you've already destroyed the reference, so the variable is no longer connected to anything. calling release on it won't work.